# While creating android release build getting jarsigner exit with code 1 error

Tags: xamarin.android, maui

#### .Net Maui (android sdk 8)

When trying to create Android apk using command line tool from the Visual studio for mac getting this error:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/34.0.52/tools/Xamarin.Android.Common.tar
gets(2386,2): error MSB6006: "jarsigner" exited with code 1.
```

#### Command I have used:

dotnet publish -f net8.0-android -c Release -p:AndroidKeyStore=true -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=myapp-key.keystore -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=mykey -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=app24 -p:AndroidSigningStorePass=app24

How to fix this error?

Comment: Check the keystore and key alias, verify the password, check the keystore format, update the Xamarin.Android tool, debug the signing process by running the "jarsigner" command manually, and check the Xamarin logs for more details.

Comment: I'm working with .Net maui now, and keystore details are proper.